# add one object to another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 objects, and I need to add one object to the other object.

```js
var loc = {
  leftArray: [],
  topArray: [],
  bottomArray: [],
  rightArray: []
}

var obj = {
  id: "ce",
  icon: "logo/image.png",
  name: "CE",
  type: "type2",
  version: 3.4
}
```

```js
var obj = {
  id: "ce",
  icon: "logo/image.png",
  name: "CE",
  type: "type2",
  version: 3.4,
  leftArray: [],
  topArray: [],
  bottomArray: [],
  rightArray: []
}
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: `var obj = Object.assign(obj, loc)` is the way out here.

Comment: you can also use merge from lodash, if you have that lib... https://lodash.com/docs/#merge

Comment: use like obj.leftArray=[]; which automatically generate new obj.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with Object.assign();

```
obj = Object.assign(obj, loc);
```

or just

```
Object.assign(obj, loc);
```

as T.J. Crowder proposed in his comment.

Comment: Just FWIW, there's no need for the assignment in this case, just `Object.assign(obj, loc);` would be sufficient. (And you certainly wouldn't want the `var`, since `obj` is already declared.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, you're right about not redeclaring the variable. I didn't know that you don't need to assign the result of Object.assign(). Thanks for the info. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: `Object.assign` returns the first object you pass in. That's so you can pass in an object initializer ("literal"), like this: `const foo = Object.assign({}, something, blah);` That's just a one-liner version of `const foo = {}; Object.assign(foo, something);` Thanks for contributing, and welcome!

Answer (score 2):

you can merge them using Spread syntax like

```
let objOne = { a: 'hi' }
let objTwo = { b: 'hello' }
let objOneAndTwo = { ...objOne, ...objTwo }; // { a: 'hi', b: 'hello' }
```

or by using Object assign:

```
let objOneAndTwo = Object.assign({}, a, b)
```

note that using this way if your objects would have properties with the same name priority will be with the most right object (in this example objectTwo)

additional info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax