# Adding one object to the property of other objects by spread operator in node js giving unnecessary properties?

Tags: javascript

My First Object is

```
conversation = {
  "members": [
    "613aa457e8d5f249922e7f86",
    "613aa457e8d5f249922e7faa"
  ],
  "_id": "613aace085dee060fdeb6a9c",
}
```

My Second object is

```
message = {
  "read": false,
  "_id": "613aadd58becf96394001efa",
  "sender": "613aa457e8d5f249922e7f86",
  "text": "hi",
  "conversation_id": "613aadcc8becf96394001ee8",
}
```

My Expected Result is

```
{
  "members": [
    "613aa457e8d5f249922e7f86",
    "613aa457e8d5f249922e7faa"
  ],
  "_id": "613aace085dee060fdeb6a9c",
  "message": {
    "read": false,
    "_id": "613aadd58becf96394001efa",
    "sender": "613aa457e8d5f249922e7f86",
    "text": "hi",
    "conversation_id": "613aadcc8becf96394001ee8",
  }
}
```

At First I tried with spread operator by following this  link

```
let new_object= { ...conversation, messages }
```

and i got the result something like this

[image]

I also tried with these way by following [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004742/add-one-object-to-another-object-in-javascript)

```
let new_object= Object.assign(conversation, message);

let new_object= Object.assign({},conversation, message);
```

But I don't get my expected result.

Comment: it looks like your `converstation` and `message` objects are completely different to what you say they are

Comment: The spread operator would do. [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/vYZxQLR?editors=0011)

Comment: There is no need to spread `messages` @JuanMendes. Because OP wants the `message` to be an individual object.

Comment: @HR01M8055 It works in this way, but i get this **conversation** and **message** object from database, and when i call that from API  , i couldn't get what i want

Comment: `let new_object= { ...conversation, messages }` does work, but if you're working with data you're getting asynchronously you may have to `await` for all the data to be returned before you can merge them together.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be loading your data from mongoose, which by default is going to decorate your objects such that they aren't the "plain old javascript objects" you think they are.

Mongoose provides a [toObject](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) method on Document that can convert an object you loaded from the DB to the plain object you're expecting. You probably want to do something like this:

```
  // assume conversationFromDb and messageFromDb are Mongoose documents
  const conversation = conversationFromDb.toObject();
  const message = messageFromDb.toObject();

  const newObject = { ...conversation, message };
```

Comment: yes mate, i am loading all of these data from mongoDB database, i am going to try this way and let you know

Comment: thank you brother, i got my solution. But now i have done it implementing mongodb aggregation framework